# :root CSS not loaded sometimes?

Tags: css, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a web application using `ASP.net` with`MVC5` and`Razor`.

I have used some variables in my CSS in order to handle repeated values in my styles, and I've done it this way:

```
:root {
    --base-color: #15616b;
    --color-bg-b-1: #15616b;
    --color-bg-b-2: #1a8b97;
    --color-bg-b-3: #6ca9b3;
    --color-bg-b-4: #a0c0c6;
    --small-tile-text: #297d88;
    --color-tile-shock: var(--color-bg-b-2);
    --color-tile-alarm: #3ab5b0;
    --color-tile-inactive: #a8dad8;
    --color-glyph-help: var(--color-bg-b-3);
    --color-h2: var(--color-bg-b-2);
    --color-loader: var(--color-bg-b-2);
    --color-form-title: #297d88;
    --color-button: #009688;
    --color-selected-row: #009688;
    --color-label: #297d88;
    --color-mybtn-hover: var(--color-bg-b-2);
    --color-mybtn: #3ab5b0;
}
```

Sometimes, when I deploy a new version of the app, these values are not loaded, and I need to refresh the page in order to see my page correctly.

The issue appears in different browsers.

What am I doing wrong? Could this be due to this line:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700);
```

Maybe if the loading fails (sometimes Chrome blocks it) everything else does?

PS. I've read online that using CSS variables could be bad, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to browser caching, that's why it will work after another refresh.

You can use a cache buster to make sure that the version you deploy is the version you want.

A cache buster might add a timestamp on the end of the include, for example:

```
//Pre cache buster
<link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

//Post cache buster
<link href="stylesheet.css?1522063943" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What this will do is force the browser to get the stylesheet again as technically it's a different url.

CSS variables aren't a bad idea at all however, I wouldn't recommend putting a variable inside of a variable like you did with:

```
--color-h2: var(--color-bg-b-2);
```

Comment: I will try the buster, thanks! Just one question: is that number after the question mark totally random?

Comment: It can be random but it's best to use a timestamp as it will never be the same

Comment: Sure it is. I'll try and let you know asap!

Comment: It worked! Just one more question: I do not change that `CSS` very often, so why's the problem? Moreover, why doesn't this affect the other `CSS` files? Is that because of the `:root` pseudoclass?

Comment: As you don't change your CSS that often your browser will cache it as it knows that it doesn't need to get it again.

With your other CSS files it may be due to the fact that they're not being load in every page (correct me if I'm wrong) so the browser may not cache it.

If you want to cache all of the files consistently I would use a .htaccess file but as you're running asp.net files I don't know if you can do it that way.